# If a user enters an invalid string option in python how should I handle the exception?

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a rock, paper, scissors, game for a user and computer and I want the user to type in one of the three options i.e "rock" but I'm not sure what kind of exception to use if the user enters say "monkey."

```
class RockPaperScissors:
    def getUserChoice(userchoice):
        while True:
            try:

                userchoice = input("Type in your choice: rock, paper, scissors: ")
                if userchoice != "rock" or userchoice != "paper" or userchoice != "scissors":
                    raise ValueError("Try typing in your choice again")
                break
            
            except:
                print("Invalid Input.")   
        return userchoice.lower()
```

Comment: Why throw at all? Just keep looping until they enter a correct option.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're right I should keep them looping but I'm not sure how exactly to keep them looping or should I even use try/except?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the code I have posted here just skips over the if statement as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you probably do not need an exception.
You probably want to loop again on input().
The following code is more explicit:

```
class RockPaperScissors:
  def getUserChoice():
    while True:
      userchoice = input("Type in your choice: rock, paper, scissors: ").lower()
        if userchoice in ( "rock", "paper" "scissors"):
          return userchoice
        else:
          print( "Invalid input. Try again.)
```

The try|except mechanism is more appropriate when you want to handle the error at an upper level.

Answer (score 0):

It's very helpful to use a sentinel value like `None`, if you want to remind the user of the input choices after each failed attempt:

```py
class RockPaperScissors:

    def getUserChoice(self):
        choice = None
        while choice not in ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors'):
            if choice is not None:
                print('Please enter only rock, paper, or scissors.')
            choice = input('Type in your choice: rock, paper, scissors: ').lower()
        return choice
```

You can also do an even shorter version in later versions of Python:

```py
class RockPaperScissors:

    def getUserChoice(self):
        prompt = 'Type in your choice: rock, paper, scissors: '
        choices = 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'
        while (choice := input(prompt).lower()) not in choices:
            print('Please enter only rock, paper, or scissors.')
        return choice
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have the user enter a number. That way, you don't have to worry about spelling:

```
class RockPaperScissors:
    def getUserChoice(options = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")):
        options_str = "\n\t" + "\n\t".join(f'{x+1}. {opt}' for x,opt in enumerate(options))
        while True:
            userchoice = input(f"Type in your choice:{options_str}\n").lower()
            try:
                userchoice = int(userchoice)
                if 1 <= userchoice <= len(options):
                    return options[int(userchoice) - 1]
            except:
                if userchoice in options:
                    return userchoice
            print("Invalid Input.")
```

Note: this uses `try/except` but only for the string-to-int conversion. Also, the code will work if the user types the word instead of a number.
Sample run:

```
>>> RockPaperScissors.getUserChoice()
Type in your choice:
    1. rock
    2. paper
    3. scissors
4
Invalid Input.
Type in your choice:
    1. rock
    2. paper
    3. scissors
3
'scissors'
```

Typing the word:

```
>>> RockPaperScissors.getUserChoice()
Type in your choice:
    1. rock
    2. paper
    3. scissors
Paper
'paper'
```

And, it works with any options:

```
>>> RockPaperScissors.getUserChoice(("C", "C++", "Python", "Java", "Prolog"))
Type in your choice:
    1. C
    2. C++
    3. Python
    4. Java
    5. Prolog
3
'Python'
```